# How to Select SimpleType from the Base File in XSD while parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have one file named base.xsd and in this I have structure like this :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:simpleType name="StringNotNull">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="AssemblyTimeDimension">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:positiveInteger">
            <xsd:attribute name="unitOfMeasure" type="AssemblyTimeUnitOfMeasure" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="AssemblyTimeUnitOfMeasure">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="minutes"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="hours"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="days"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="weeks"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="months"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="years"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have another file in which I have a structure like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="base.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="BabyProducts">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="AlertType" type="StringNotNull" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element name="AssemblyTime" type="AssemblyTimeDimension" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have elements schemaTypeName.Name in a String variable. How can I find the SimpleType in base.xsd with this Name and its sub tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying parse/read the XML, you can Linq XML. Following example shows you how to parse and access elements/attributes. You might want to add some error checking (null check or valid values etc.). You would check against your schemaTypeName.Name compared with a.Value in the first lookup below.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("base.xsd");
var element = doc.Descendants()
                 .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attributes()
                 .Any(a => a.Name=="name" && a.Value == "StringNotNull")) as XElement;

var minLength = element.Descendants()
                       .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "minLength")
                       .Attribute("value").Value;
var maxLength = element.Descendants()
                       .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "maxLength")
                       .Attribute("value").Value;
```

For schema validation, good option would be to use actual [schema validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: using System.Xml.Linq; See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I am unable to add the reference System.Xml.Linq it does not exist ?

Comment: What version of .Net framework are you using? Xml.Linq is available from .Net 3.5 and up.

Comment: Does not contain a defination for FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: You will need to add both using statements for linq and xml: "using System.Linq;" and then "using System.Xml.Linq;" at the top of you code.

Comment: would you please review me question again and suggest me about complexType ? @loopedcode